# Lovecraftesque Story with a Giant Stairwell

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Long time ago, I read a story which in retrospect I'd classify as Lovecraftesque in style, though I doubt it was one of HPL's own works (it doesn't match any of HPL's stories I've read long afterwards). I don't remember the title nor the author thereof. It had the following elements:

- One of the characters managed to escape from an eldritch temple of sorts, but had an urge to return, crawling back on his arms and legs in his sleep.
- I remember the character described as having sores on his limbs, but I don't remember if it was in the process of praying, escaping, or trying to return.
- The temple was a giant well-like hole in the ground, with a spiral staircase and niches in the walls.
- The eldritch entities that demanded worship were normally invisible; it took drinking some special substance to begin seeing them, but the effect of that was lasting.
- The entities' shape included a vermiform body, though I'm not sure if it had any limbs; IIRC they also included a sphere or halo or something like that on top.
- The events of the story were taking place during some expedition through wilderness or at least deep foreign land.
- I'm inclined to believe that the story dates back to the 90s at the latest, and is likely older than that.
- I'm not sure what was the date *within* the story, but it was probably no later than the traditional Lovecraftian era.

What story might this be?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The story you're looking for is **The People of the Pit** by **Abraham Merritt**, published in 1918. You can read it [here](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks06/0601991h.html):

Everything you remember fits with the story: the temple in the well, the worm-like people, the expedition of a sort, the main character's "sores", his urge to come back, the Lovecraftian atmosphere.

It's a solid and enjoyable story, by the way.

Comment: Wow, that’s a great story!